# VS2017 version 15.8.3 successfully compiles inline method without returning a required value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I compiled the following code with VS2017 version 15.8.3. Its Warning Level is set to `/W4`. The code contains two simple getters, one of them `GetM()` is inline.

The `GetM()` inline getter does not have a `return` statement. However, VS2017 happily compiled the code without any warning or error.

The `GetN()` method will result in `error C4716: 'Simple::GetN': must return a value` if its `return n;` statement is commented out.

```
class Simple
{
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;

public:
    int GetM() const { /* No return here. */ }
    int GetN() const;
};

int Simple::GetN() const
{
    return n;
    // No return here results in compiler error below. 
    // error C4716: 'Simple::GetN': must return a value
}

int main()
{
    Simple obj;
}
```

Question: Should the compiler also generate `error C4716` for the inline method `GetM()`?

Comment: Maybe you would get the warning if you actually called the function

Comment: note that it is non-conforming for the compiler to reject this program (there is only UB if execution  enters and leaves the function with the missing return statement)

Comment: Adding the compiler option `/Wall` gives: `warning C4514: 'Simple::GetM': unreferenced inline function has been removed`  live link: https://godbolt.org/z/MQq4Bf

Answer (score 2):

A method fully defined inside the class definition is sort-of inlined. If it isn't expanded directly inline where it's used, it is compiled outside of the class body. This is the magic sauce that allows a method to see any members that were defined after it in the class.

If it is not used, maybe the compiler doesn't look at it deeply enough to spot the mistake. Maybe it doesn't look at it at all. Maybe it generates a warning and maybe not. That's up to the compiler. Visual Studio seems to have elected report a missing return statement as an error, but to not inspect an unused `inline` (or sort-of inlined) function.

By changing `main` to

```
int main()
{
    Simple obj;
    obj.GetM();
}
```

I can make Visual Studio produce error C4716 for `gGetM` as the function now must be compiled, inlined or not.

I can also

```
inline int Simple::GetN() const 
{ 
}
```

to explicitly make `GetN` `inline` and "eliminate" the error.

This is all highly compiler, and possibly even compiler option, specific.